# don't know what my Error is (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Implement a class Car with the following properties. A car has a
>   certain fuel efficiency (measured in miles/gallon) and a certain
>   amount of fuel in the gas tank. The efficiency is specified in the
>   constructor, and the initial fuel level is 0. Supply a method drive
>   that simulates driving the car for a certain distance, reducing the
>   fuel level in the gas tank, and methods getGasLevel, to return the
>   current fuel level, and addGas, to tank up. Sample usage:
>
> ```
> myHybrid = Car(50)
> myHybrid.addGas(20)
> myHybrid.drive(100)
> print(myHybrid.getGasLevel())
> ```
>
> Write a main program to test your class.

my code:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, fuelEfficiency):
        super(Car, self).__init__()
        self.fuelEfficiency = fuelEfficiency
        self.fuelLevel = 0  #   In gallons


    #   Returns the amount of gas
    def getGasLevel(self):
        return self.fuelLevel

    #   Adds gas
    def addGas(self, gasToAdd):
        self.fuelLevel += gasToAdd

    #   Simulates driving car for a given distance
    #   and reduces the amount of gas based on the
    #   fuelEfficiency.
    def drive(self, distanceInMiles):
        gasToRemove = self.fuelEfficiency * distanceInMiles

        self.fuelLevel -= gasToRemove

        #   Ensure we don't go below zero gas
        self.fuelLevel = max(self.fuelLevel,0)


def main():

    myHybrid=Car(50)
    myHybrid.addGas(20)
    myHybrid.drive(100)
    print(myHybrid.getGasLevel())
```

Comment: Why do you think there is an "error"? What's happening that isn't what you expect?

Comment: Why do you tag this as both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x]? It can't be both.

Comment: sorry i'm a complete beginner so i just tried to tag it on both versions

Comment: asongtoruin, i'm not getting any sort of value

Comment: When you open IDLE does it say (3.x.x) or (2.7.x) in the title (after your filename).

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that code? If you did it is surprising that you have **exactly** the same spacing  and comments as this guys... https://github.com/MosheBerman/oop-1/blob/master/1.3/Car.py

Comment: 2.7 neil that what i get

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to call `main()`

add the following lines at the bottom (no indentation):

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: Your code is working, it outputs `0`. It does exactly what it is supposed to do, but as noted in another answer, you have made and error in the math.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. You do not invoke your `main()`.  I suspect this was a copy and paste error.
2. You messed up your math for reducing fuel.  Instead of `self.fuelEfficiency * distanceInMiles` it should be `distanceInMiles / self.fuelEfficiency`.  Your current code is subtracting 100*50 gallons instead of 12 gallons.  Thus, obviously, your fuel will go to 0.

## New code

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, fuelEfficiency):
        super(Car, self).__init__()
        self.fuelEfficiency = fuelEfficiency
        self.fuelLevel = 0  #   In gallons

    #   Returns the amount of gas
    def getGasLevel(self):
        return self.fuelLevel

    #   Adds gas
    def addGas(self, gasToAdd):
        self.fuelLevel += gasToAdd

    #   Simulates driving car for a given distance
    #   and reduces the amount of gas based on the
    #   fuelEfficiency.
    def drive(self, distanceInMiles):
        gasToRemove = distanceInMiles / self.fuelEfficiency
        self.fuelLevel -= gasToRemove
        #   Ensure we don't go below zero gas
        self.fuelLevel = max(self.fuelLevel,0)


def main():
    myHybrid=Car(50)
    myHybrid.addGas(20)
    myHybrid.drive(100)
    print(myHybrid.getGasLevel())

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```